# Filter a view to show only entries from a specific month

Tags: filter, view

I have a SharePoint view with a lot of colums. One of the colums is "created" which is the date the entry was created.

When I want to export the view for a specific month only, it's a bit tedious since I have to export the whole list of entries and then delete the months that I do not want in Excel.

I see that I can add another view with a filter. But, I do not know how to define the month in the filter options (Show items when column created = "xxxxx")

I have tried the following: `'MONTH(May)'; 'MONTH (5)';` but I get the "Filter value is not in supported date format" message.

Could someone push me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

[image]

The problem is that you have to specify the year as well.

My example filters the items that are created between 1st and 31st of May, 2016

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way from Gintas's answer is:

You can create one **calculated column** with **return type of Number** and apply this formula `=TEXT([DateField];"mmmm")`. Then in a view you can see new column with month values.

Then from modify this view, you can filter the view by using this calculated column and your **desired month name**. You can filter the view using only one condition.